# How to fix "Too Many Redirects" error in HTTP

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to set up a login/signup website (Using Firebase Auth), and I am getting a "too many redirects" error when I try to sign up on my site. How can I fix this?

Running HTML5 with Firebase Auth

```
<form action="index.html" style="border:1px solid #ccc">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
                <hr>

                <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
                <br>
                <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
                <br>

                <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

                <div class="clearfix">
                    <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
                </div>
                <img src="BF116-11KM.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">

            </div>
        </form>
        <p id="log"></p>
    </center>
</div>

<script>
    function logSubmit(event)
    {
        var database = firebase.database();
        function testResults(form)
        {
            var email = form.email.value;
            var password = form.psw.value;
        }

        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function (error)
        {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            log.textContent = 'Sorry, Something went wrong. Please try again in a moment';
            // ...
        });
        log.textContent = 'Signup Complete! Please login on the main page';

        event.preventDefault();
    }

    const form = document.getElementById('form');
    const log = document.getElementById('log');
    form.addEventListener('submit', logSubmit);


</script>
```

Expected results would be the account appearing in my firebase console, but actual results include the "too many redirects" error.

Comment: For starters `email` and `password` are undefined variables when you call that on page load as shown. You need to create user after they enter credentials and use a form submit listener to know when they are done. Then you can access their credential values to send to firebase

Comment: Hello, I tried that, and it still gives me the error. thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Two notices:

- your second input-element (password) never closes
- how is the index.html supposed to support your form-submit?

Comment: okay, I fixed the first problem, but i am confused about the second. can you clarify>

Comment: The "action"-attribute of your <form> points to a .html file. How is the html file supposed to receive data - don`t you process your answer in a .php file or something similar?